# Cannot find nested contours

Tags: opencv, contour

I'm using `findContours()` and `drawContours()` method to find the contours in my binary image. However this is my output:

[image: my output]

If I further threshold my image such as the rectangle gets blurred, then the inner is visible (notice the outer and inner curves are merged at the bottom left):

[image: notice the outer and inner curves are merged at the bottom left]

Can you please explain this and how to solve it?

Following is my code snippet:

```
void cb_thresh(int,void*)
{vector< vector<Point> > contours; 

vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
threshold(src, thr,threshval, 255,THRESH_BINARY);
namedWindow("threshold",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("threshold",thr);
findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ); // Find the contours in the image

Scalar color( 255,255,255);

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour

{
drawContours(thr, contours,i, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
}
namedWindow("dst",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("dst",thr);
}
```

Do notice that I've removed the hierarchy of the contours.

Comment: I have tried changing the contour extraction method but getting the same output in all 4 retrieval methods.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line `drawContours(thr, contours,i, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );`. Passing a parameter CV_FILLED will fill the entire area inside a contour. Hence the rectangle was filled. One may replace `CV_FILLED` with any positive integer.